# MSBuild in VSTS deploy web app on root

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-devops, msdeploy

I am trying to Continuous Delivery my ASP.NET WEB API 2 app with Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS).

I created Release with `Deploy Azure App Service` task with default settings (i changed only `Package or Folder` field to match my `bin\Release` folder)

Build and deploy were successful, but nothing changed. When I open `DebugConsole/CMD` in Diagnostic Console (`app-name.scm.azurewebsites.net`) I saw that VSO put all binaries to the `...\wwwroot`, while Visual Studio puts all binaries to `...\wwwroot\bin` folder.

WWWROOT structure with Visual Studio `Publish...` task

```
...\wwwroot 
       Web.Config
       Global.asax
       packages.config
       bin\
           *.dll
```

WWWROOT structure with Visual Studio Online `Deploy Azure App Service` task

```
...\wwwroot 
       Web.Config
       Global.asax
       packages.config          
       *.dll
```

How can I set target folder on deploy?

Comment: I made a test with an asp.net web api project (New project=>Visual C#=>Web=>Asp.net Web Application=>Web API), I can't reproduce this issue, the library files are in the wwwroot\bin folder. What's the details of your build definition (e.g. create package and Deploy Azure App service steps/tasks)? Share detail build and release log here or on the OneDrive.

Comment: Can you share the build definition settings?